# Code analyzers for detecting concurrency issues in F#

Tags: concurrency, f#, deadlock, race-condition, code-analysis

I'm looking for some code analyzing tool (either static or dynamic analysis) that can detect concurrency issues like race conditions or deadlock in F# programs.

I know F# is based on the 'Actor model' and that it has some inherent concurrency support, so I'm assuming that there is a possibility of issues like race conditions and deadlock arising. If so, I'm wandering if there is any tool that can take in the F# source code and find program points where such issues can occur.

Does anyone have any ideas about this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there are any tools for this.  It's still a very hard problem (given the program state explosion.) Microsoft Research developed the [CHESS tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/chess-find-and-reproduce-heisenbugs-in-concurrent-programs/?from=https%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2Fchess%2F#!additional-information) for concurrency testing Win32 and .NET code (oriented towards locks and mutable data)  The tool is still experimental and I don't think further versions have been developed or at least published.

IMHO The best approach for this problem is still model checking. That is develop an abstract model from your problem and use a specific tool for analyzing this model.  For example [CSP](https://cocotec.io/fdr/manual/cspm.html) is a language for modeling interactions (oriented towards the actor model) and [FDR](https://cocotec.io/fdr/) is a tool for finding concurrency issues in those models.

On a sidenote F# is not based on the actor model. You can implement the actor model using [mailboxes](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/concurrency-actor-model/) but you can also use locks and mutable data (relevant since a checker tool would need to check both approaches).